# Find the n word in a String

Tags: java

Inside the `for` loop i want to read the string `line`, check if the next word is a number, get it.

The loop defines which occurence I want. `i=1` , would be first occurrence of line, `i=2`, second,etc...

```
String output = "line 10 bla bla bla line 20, line 30"
for(int i=1;i<=3;i++) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(output);
            while(scanner.hasNext()) {
                String word = scanner.next();    
                if(word.equals("line")) {
                    if(scanner.hasNext()) {
                        String nextWord = scanner.next().replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");
                        if(nextWord.chars().allMatch(Character::isDigit)) {
                            //I want to stop reading and Just go to the next loop and check for the i occurence
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
      }
```

**The output would be**

> when `i=1` -> 10
>
> when `i=2` -> 20
>
> when `i=3` -> 30

Comment: Surely if you take all of the non-digits out of a string with `replaceAll`, then all of the characters are digits? Why bother with regex and streams, instead of simply "true"?

Comment: lol        ..............

Answer (score 0):

You could use a string array to hold all the words separately and then check for "line"in the array and the succeeding number.

```
String output = "line 10 bla bla bla line 20, line 30"
int i=0;
int occurences=0;
String[] wordArray=new String[50];
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(output);
            while(scanner.hasNext()) {
            wordArray[i++]=scanner.next();
            }
for(i=0;i<wordArray.length;i++)
{
   if(wordArray[i].equals("line"))
    {
      System.out.println("occurence: "+ ++occurences);
      if(wordArray[i+1].matches("\\d+")
      System.out.println(wordArray[i+1]);
      else
      System.out.println("not a number");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is only how to break inner loop, here is the solution:

```
String output = "line 10 bla bla bla line 20, line 30"

for(int i=1;i<=3;i++) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(output);
    boolean found= false;
            while(scanner.hasNext() && !found) {
                String word = scanner.next();    
                if(word.equals("line")) {
                    if(scanner.hasNext()) {
                        String nextWord = scanner.next().replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");
                        if(nextWord.chars().allMatch(Character::isDigit)) {
                            found = true;
                            //I want to stop reading and Just go to the next loop and check for the i occurence
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the entire line and remove the commas first, then store space separated words in an array of String, to check if the next word following the word "line" is a number use a try catch block. If its a number it will be saved as an int.

String output = "line 10 bla bla bla line 20, line 30";

```
    output = output.replaceAll(",","");
    String[] words = output.split(" ");
    for(int i = 0; i<words.length-1;i++){
        if(words[i].equals("line")){
           try{
               Integer.parseInt(words[i+1]);
               System.out.println("is number");
               int digit = Integer.parseInt(words[i+1]);
               System.out.println("Digit is " +digit);

           }
           catch(NumberFormatException e){
             System.out.println("is not a number");

           }
        }
    }
```